# karaf blueprint "Failure" while extending console

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I am using Karaf 2.3.1. I was following Apache Karaf Manual exercise "Extending the console" page no. 105. I followed all the instruction ditto, with a few deviations. I am able to load the bundle HelloShellCommand into Karaf. It threw me a bundle Id. But the command "test.hello" is not working.

karaf@root> osgi:classes is showing org/apache/karaf.shell/samplesHelloShellCommand.class

karaf@root> test.hello is showing command not found

karaf@root> osgi:list is showing Blueprint "Failure" for the given bundle.

I did deviate from the given instruction in "Compiling the JAR" section in following steps:

1. Let's try to build the jar: I did build the jar from Eclipse. File-Export-Java-Jar File.
2. Then run "mvn install": This is where I did not understand how Maven will use the .jar file. It is looking for pom.xml. So, I went into root directory and ran "mvn install". It went through successfully.
3. osgi:install .., also went through successfully. But I suspect Blueprint.xml did not go through.

I need help in:

1. How to resolve this?
2. How to know in Karaf what commands are installed with each bundle?
3. .jar file created in step-1 is different from "mvn install" which uses pom.xml. Is there something I am missing? How to make mvn use the .jar?
4. And why blueprint.xml did not load?

Thanks in advance

Further, we have this stackoverflow:

2013-07-27 19:44:30,733 | ERROR | rint Extender: 2 
                        | BlueprintContainerImpl
                        | container.BlueprintContainerImpl  393 
                        | 7 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.1.0 
                        | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle null

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:570)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:348)[:1.7.0-ea]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.readDirectives
      (BlueprintContainerImpl.java:211)[7:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.1.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun
      (BlueprintContainerImpl.java:283)[7:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.1.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run     
       (BlueprintContainerImpl.java:261)[7:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.1.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call
       (Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0-ea]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run
       (ExecutorServiceWrapper.java:106)[7:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.1.0]
at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run
       (DiscardableRunnable.java:48)[7:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.1.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call
       (Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun (FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201
       (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run
       (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
       (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
       (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)[:1.7.0-ea]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)[:1.7.0-ea]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1)
Is the bundle started? Did you use osgi:install -s with starting? If not you should start the bundle with start [bundleId]

Regarding 2)
Issue help at command line, it'll list all available commands. Using command -h will give you a overview of the command itself.

Regarding 3) 
forget about creating a jar file from eclipse that won't work. Only with the maven pom you'll have a bundle that contains a valid Manifest unless you added this yourself (which I didn't see in your description)

Regarding 4) 
Most likely your bundle either isn't started or it doesn't contain a valid manifest which in turn doesn't start the blueprint extender.

Besides that all those questions are usually best asked at the karaf users mailinglist

**EDIT:**
For finding the reason why a bundle did fail do a bundle:info on the bundle with the given ID
it should also show you why a blueprint failed.

Comment: 1. Yes. Bundle is Active State. But Blueprint is in Failure state. 2. I was actually looking for an osgi command which would tell me about the life cycle of a bundle. I did use osgi:list and osgi:classes but it did not tell me about what commands I added to the bundle. Thanks for your advice I did raise this query in Nabble forum.